# "java -version" command has different results in Inno Setup

Tags: java, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to build up a installer for my software by Inno Setup.

But a weird thing happened：

I try to run the Pascal code to get the Java version in Inno Setup script

```pascal
Exec('cmd.exe', '/c java  -version 2> ' + tempDirPath+jdkVersionInfoFile, '', 
     SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

The result is `java verison "1.6"`.

And when I typed the command `java -version` in console window, then I get the result is `java version "1.8"`.

Why are the results different?

Comment: Probably the two ways you are running `java -version` are using different paths (or whatever) to find the `java` command.  Check the `%PATH%` settings.

Comment: I execute the command `echo %PATH%` in two ways , the results are same.And I find that  `java 1.6`,`java 1.7`,`java 1.8` have be installed in my PC  . Finally I removed the `java 1.6` , It works well.But I still do not know why there would be such a result T_T...

Comment: Yes ... but did you ensure that the correct %PATH%  is used when you call `Exec` in Pascal?

Comment: What does `where java.exe` output for console window and Inno Setup? + Show us the `%PATH%`.

Comment: The result of the command `where java.exe` is                                                                       >C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\bin\java.exe
>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe
>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe                                         I guess that if it run as  **administrator** when I execute my installer ,bacause the installer will write some files to the `C:\Program Files (x86)` directory.But when I typed the command in `DOS window` ,it run as **normal user**?

Comment: If both environments have the same `%PATH%`, it should not matter if you have administrator privileges or not. The same executable should be found. Double check that the `%PATH%` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot imagine how exactly this happens on your machine without more details, differences like this typically stem from the fact that Inno Setup is 32-bit application.

It's likely that 32-bit version of Java is run by Inno Setup (32-bit application) and 64-bit version of Java is run by Windows command interpreter (64-bit application). And you have different versions installed for these platforms.

(Assuming that you run 64-bit version of Windows).

See [Install Mode: 32-bit vs. 64-bit](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) article in Inno Setup documentation.